# Bom Dia, fiz este codigo para registar um utilizador, mas queria que cada vez que ele insere na caixa de texto um email ja registado que ele o indique

Tags: php, html

Registo.php

```
<?php
//Conexão  à BD
require('ligacao.php');

    $Nome=$_REQUEST['Nome'];
    $Pwd_Utilizador=$_REQUEST['Pwd_Utilizador'];
    $Tipo_Utilizador=$_REQUEST['Tipo_Utilizador'];
    $email=$_REQUEST['email'];

$insere="Insert into utilizador(Nome,Pwd_Utilizador,Tipo_Utilizador,email) values('$Nome', '$Pwd_Utilizador',$Tipo_Utilizador,'$email')";

$result=mysqli_query($ligax,$insere);
// $mensagem="Dados inseridos";
   // header('Location: Index.html');
 //}else{ 
         //$mensagem="Dados não inseridos";
        // header('Location: registo.php');
//}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="2; URL='Index.html'"/>
<p style="text-align:center;font-size:300%;">
   Bem Vindo
</p>
<?php
mysqli_close($ligax); //fecha conexão
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Registo.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="PT"><!-- Basic -->
<head>
<body>

    <header class="top-navbar">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
            <div class="container">
            <a class="navbar-brand">
                    <img src="images/RestauranteAraújoRocha.png" alt="" style="width:150px;height:100px;" />
                </a>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbars-rs-food">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Bem Vindo Por Favor Inicie Sessão para entrar</a></li>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>  
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
</head>
    <!-- Start All Pages -->
    <div class="all-page-title page-breadcrumb">
        <div class="container text-center">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <h1>Registo de Utilizador</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

<div class="container"
    <!-- End All Pages -->
   <p></p>
    <form class="form-signin" method="GET" action="registo.php">
        <label class="sr-only">Nome Utilizador:</label>
        <input type="text" name="Nome" id="Nome" placeholder="Nome" class="form-control" required autofocus><br>
       <label class="sr-only">Senha:</label>
       <input type="password" name="Pwd_Utilizador" id="Pwd_Utilizador" class="form-control" placeholder="Senha" required><br>
       <label class="sr-only">Email:</label>
       <input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" required><br>
       <label class="sr-only">Tipo Utilizador:</label>
       <input type="text" name="Tipo_Utilizador" id="Tipo_Utilizador" class="form-control" readonly Value="2" hidden><br>
       <button type="submit" value="Registar" id="submit" name="submit">Registar</button>
       <button><a href="Utili.html">Login</button>
       </form>
</div>
<p>
                     
    </p>
    <p>
                     
    </p>
<div class="contact-imfo-box">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4 arrow-right">
                    <i class="fa fa-volume-control-phone"></i>
                    <div class="overflow-hidden">
                        <h4>Telemóvel</h4>
                        <p class="lead">
                            (+351)255 245 343
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 arrow-right">
                    <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>
                    <div class="overflow-hidden">
                        <h4>Email</h4>
                        <p class="lead">
                            RestauranteAR@gmail.com
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i>
                    <div class="overflow-hidden">
                        <h4>Localização</h4>
                        <p class="lead">
                            767, Castelo de Paiva, Portugal
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Você pode fazer um select antes de inserir, se retornar algo no select não insere pois ja existe.

Answer (score 0):

Eu nunca escrevi php, mas penso que a logica será essa:

```
$emailList="Select email from utilizador";
if($email = $emailList ){ 
   echo "Email já inserido"
}
else{
   $insere="Insert into utilizador(Nome,Pwd_Utilizador,Tipo_Utilizador,email) 
    values('$Nome', '$Pwd_Utilizador',$Tipo_Utilizador,'$email')";
}
```